# JavaScript/Node.JS returning a promise in another promise not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, promise

I'm a bit confused with those promise things and can't understand why I can't return a promise into another promise. My problem is the following, I have a function save :

```
save(Driver) {
    this.exists(Driver).then(exist => {
        if(exist) {
            return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                if (exist === true) {
                    resolve(true);
                } else if (exist === false) {
                    resolve(false);
                } else {
                    reject(err);
                }
            });
        }
    });
};
```

As easy as it is, when I try to call that function as following :

```
save(driver).then(this.common.saveSuccess(res))
            .catch(this.common.noSuccess(res));
```

I'm getting an error saying that `Cannot read property 'then' of undefined` and I can't understand why as I'm returning a promise.
Thank for the help

Comment: You didn’t return anything from `save()`. `return this.exists(Driver).then(…` Also, where’s `result` defined?

Comment: yes sorry I was trying to simplify the code and forgot yo change the text, I fixed that

Comment: Please fix it in the question as well. [edit]

Comment: You mean that the return inside `this.exists(Driver).then(…` is not the return of the function ?

Comment: No. `exist => { … }` is another function, in a shorthand (an “arrow function”).

Comment: oh okay my bad, then I should actually get the value exist and stored it in a variable and test if it's true or false after and so return the promise right ?

Comment: No, you should just add `return` like in my comment. `p.then(f)` adds an operation to transform the resolved value of `p` with `f` and returns a new promise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `save` function is very complicated. You don't need nested promise here, just return the result (promise) from `this.exists` function:

```
save(Driver) {
  return this.exists(Driver);
};
```

Also, you use this function incorrectly. `save` function can be resolved with `true` or `false` values, so you need to validate this value in `then` callback and use `catch` callback for possible errors:

```
save(driver)
  .then(exists => {
    if (exists) {
      this.common.saveSuccess(res);
    } else {
      this.common.noSuccess(res)
    }
  })
  .catch(err => // process error here);
```